# how to keep text on one line using css or javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'd like to keep text on one line corresponding to the width of the container using css or javascript.
For example, when the width of the container is fixed and the length of text is longer, the font size of the text should be smaller to keep it on one line.

Comment: You could try using “calc”, but I don’t think it’s possible to have the font size be relative to the container width (yet), but you can make it relative to the viewport?

Comment: For example:
container width: 300px
text font size: 50px
When the text is "123", it is on one line within the container.
But when the text is "1234" or "12345", it overflows the container.
I'd like to keep the text on one line to make the font size of the text smaller.

Comment: Please may you out this in the question rather than the comments? It’s not fun reading code on one line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a popular jQuery library that can be used for this, I believe it's simply called Fit Text.

It will automatically resize text so that it will fit on one line within its parent container.

A quick Google search turned up the following options:

- http://fittextjs.com/ - uses jQuery
- https://github.com/rikschennink/fitty - doesn't use jQuery